# Alter identity column to add composite key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table called let's say Jam which looks like this:

```
DateTimeCol,
Id,
A,
B,
C, so on
```

Id is an `Identity (1,1)` column, I need to change it to composite key with `DateTimeCol`. I asked google how to "alter table alter identity column add composite key SQL Server" and some variations but I can't find what I am looking for (even on SOF).

So how do I do it?

Edit 1: Why do we want to do it:

The data was coming from a third party API outside of our control. After a couple of million rows the client started crashing. We figured out that the Id is not unique after all. However combined with date time it is unique.

Comment: what is the problem and how do you expect the identity to work in the composite? If you want it to generate separate sequences based on the DateTimeCol value, that is not possible.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? An `Identity` column is a good choice for a surrogate key because it's database generated and as long as no one mess with it manually it will be unique (NOTE: it is possible to reseed or manually insert values to an identity column, so it's not guaranteed to be unique) - why would you want to add another column to this key? Also, note that using a surrogate key does not relieve you from having to specify a unique index/constraint natural key as well

Comment: @GabrielDurac it is possible, just not like this...

Comment: @ZoharPeled the implication was that it is not possible to get this behavior using an identity column. You can find workarounds for nearly any request, but that does not mean you should.

Comment: Gabrial and Zohar, the data was coming from a third party api outside of our control. after couple of million rows the client started crashing, we figured out that the Id is not unique afterall. however combined with date time it is unique. hope that helps

Comment: If the `IDENTITY` is reusing previous values, this means that *someone* has reseeded it. That isn't the `IDENTITY`'s fault. On it's own an `IDENTITY` doesn't guarantee uniqueness. There are only 2 things that guarantee uniqueness in SQL Server: A Primary Key and a Unique Index. Either must be used in conjunction with an `IDENTITY` to ensure it remains unique in the table.

Comment: Create your own primary key on the table and create indexes on `(id)` and `(datetimecol)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a column to the primary key of a table can be done by dropping the existing primary key constraint and adding a new one.
The fact that the current primary key happens to be a single column which is an identity doesn't change that - however, it does bring all kinds of interesting questions, which I will ask you after I'll show you the code:

```
ALTER TABLE Jam DROP CONSTRAINT pk_Jam;

ALTER TABLE Jam ADD CONSTRAINT pk_Jam PRIMARY KEY (DateTimeCol, Id);
```

That's it. Now the `Jam` table's primary key is the combination of `DateTimeCol` and `Id`.

However:

A surrogate key should hold no business meaning. If it does, you're using it wrong.
Assuming it doesn't, I would rather fix the problem that's causing the identity column to duplicate values in the first place over adding another column to the primary key.

This problem might be caused by one of the following:

1. using [`set identity_insert on`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
2. using [`dbcc checkident(reseed, x)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
3. using [`truncate table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Given the fact that `truncate table` will remove all rows from the table, I highly doubt this is what you're looking for.
I would find the most likely suspect to be `set identity_insert on` so I would start looking in your code base for this, and then for `dbcc checkident(reseed`.

You might also want to read my blog post entitled [SQL Server’s identity column misconceptions](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/10/06/sql-servers-identity-column-misconceptions/)

Comment: Thanks Zohar, i'll give it a try in a few minutes, you are right the fix should have been in the root cause but the root cause lies beyond our control in a thrid party api.

Comment: You wrote it's an identity column, so I assumed the 3rd party API just inserts records to your table - and if you can change the table's primary key, you should also be able to check what's the problem with the identity column...